# Kendo grid DataSourceRequest parsing numeric filter as double

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm working with a Kendo MVC grid which upon filtering a column of type `long`, the value passed to the controller action under `DataSourceRequest.Filters` is of type `double`. This is causing me problems as I'm dynamically building filter criteria for the ORM and it's unable to implicitly cast a `double` to a `long`.

View model:

```
public class AttendeeViewModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long BookingId { get; set; }
}
```

Minified initialization of the grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<AttendeeViewModel>()
  .Name("Grid")
  .EnableCustomBinding(true)
  .DataSource(ds => ds
    .Ajax()
    .Read(r => r.Action("Grid_Read", "AttendeeController"))
    .Model(m =>
    {
        m.Id(x => x.Id);
        m.Field("Id", typeof(long));        // These type definitions don't
        m.Field("BookingId", typeof(long)); // seem to make a difference
    })
    .ServerOperation(true)
  )
  .Columns(c =>
  {
    c.Bound(m => m.BookingId)
        .Title("Booking ID")
        // Using the UI method from another question to prevent decimal places in filter
        .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("eq")
          .ShowOperators(false))
          .UI("gridNumericFilter"));
    c.Bound(m => m.Id)
        .Title("Attendee ID")
        .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("eq")
          .ShowOperators(false))
          .UI("gridNumericFilter"));
  })
  .Filterable(f =>
  {
    f.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row);
    f.Extra(false);
  })
)
```

Upon filtering, the following HTTP query string is sent to the controller method:

```
?page=1&pageSize=20&group=&filter=Id~eq~30622
```

With signature:

```
public ActionResult Grid_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request) {...}
```

Which for some reason parses the filter as a double:

```
((Kendo.Mvc.FilterDescriptor)request.Filters[0]).Value.GetType().Name
"Double"
```

**How can I get the `DataSourceRequest` to parse the correct property type - `long` instead of `double`?**

Comment: Why didn't you parse in controller Grid_Read method ?

Comment: @MuratGündeş The parsing seems to be done by the `DataSourceRequestAttribute` before the request reaches the controller action. The filtering needs to be dynamic and there are various other column types. I could hard-code behavior for specific column names but this seems hacky.

Comment: Just curious, have you tried using Int64?

Comment: `Int64 == long`